# Does iOS 6 devices request old pages again

Tags: http, caching, ios6, browser-cache

It is commonly known that iOS 6 often caches more than it should, especially POST requests. This breaks webbapps that depend on requests reaching the server.

**I have found a reverse problem with iOS 6 cache, namely that it re-requests old pages again.** It seems verify the cache history by requesting all the pages again. I found a trail of "old" requested pages coming from users a few seconds apart in my server logs.

Re-requesting old GETs should be no problem in general. In my case however I have a system that archives old data that is no longer needed and these "old" requests keep bringing that data back. I've seen requests that are at least 3-4 weeks old resurface.

**Have anyone else experienced this situation?** Does it happen on other devices or is it (another) problem with the iOS cache?

EDIT: It might be only iOS 6.0.1 devices that does this and only while on a WiFi connection.